# Recovering Java file after unpredictable shutdown

Tags: java, eclipse, restore

I was writing lots of code in Eclipse when suddenly unpredictable shutdown has occurred. Now when I open Eclipse I have only the window in workspace and very long one line (crossed red line).

I've tried to restore my file via LocalHistory, but there's only 50-60 lines of code (my Java file consisted about 1500, there was a lot of comments, in LocalHistory I don't have any comments at all).

Screenshot of workspace is here:

[image: Screenshot of workspace is here]

Comment: This is one of the reasons most of us use some form of source code control software.  Have a look at Mercurial, CSV or Git.

Comment: @markspace : it think you meant CVS instead of CSV. Anyway it is bad suggestion.

Comment: Local History should have the file unless you typed 1500 lines in just a few minutes -- anyway, better get to work, there's no other magic to restore files.

Comment: Also, in workspace folder i have this file, it even has a size(35kb). But when i open it i see only empty blank

Comment: @Rus9Mus9 Tried to open it with another text editor different than Eclipse?